# How to Chromecast a file (not a link) with javascript

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, chromecast

I want to create a program that casts a file with subtitles using javascript

```
const ChromecastAPI = require('chromecast-api')

const client = new ChromecastAPI()

client.on('device', function (device) {
    if(device.friendlyName === "S70PCI" ){ 

      **//this one works**
      var mediaURL = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/big_buck_bunny_1080p.mp4"
      **//this one doesn't work**
      var mediaURL = "file:///E:/Download/Movies/Curb.Your.Enthusiasm.S11E02.1080p.WEB.H264-GGWP[TGx]/curb.your.enthusiasm.s11e02.1080p.web.h264-ggwp.mp4"

      console.log("Playting the device:")
      device.play(mediaURL, function (err){
        if(!err) {
          console.log("Playing success")}
        else{
          console.log(err, "run into an error while trying to play ", device.friendlyName)}
      })
    }

})
```

When I play a link to the tv it works fine, but when I it using a file path I get an error:

```
[1] Error: Load failed
```

I guess it fails because it just tells the TV the enter the link and not actually stream it from the computer, and the file doesn't exist on the web...

**Is there any way I could stream the file to a link/webpage
or stream it directly from my computer?**

thanks for helping!

Comment: You can't load that `mediaURL` usefully.  You first need to get a file/blob reference to it (by having the user drag/drop the file, or using a file input).  Then, you'll probably have to actually play that video locally on the casting device (perhaps in the background) and send it as a MediaStream over WebRTC to the receiving chromecast.